# Is this really a me-too non-answer?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, me-too-answers

This answer, which I have slightly edited after it was posted, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46784458/721644, was deleted. I assume mainly because it begins *"Having the same error message"*.

However it does propose a solution. That it is dubious why that would work is another matter, I have no means to try that, but it did propose a solution.

Should we delete such answers?

Comment: Might be because of the "having the same error" sentence, but  I would have voted to delete because you state that you don't have any clue what the problem is or why your method solves it.

Comment: It is an answer, but he sure tried hard to make it look like it wasn't.  Not so sure it is going to be missed.  Consider reposting it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It fooled two reviewers and a moderator. As Hans Passant says, it did a remarkably good job of hiding its essential "answer" character.

I made a couple of tweaks to the formatting/presentation and undeleted it. It *does* attempt to provide an answer to the question, even if the answerer doesn't know why the fix worked.

This Meta question prompted a follow-up flag that caused me to take another look at it. It would have been equally as effective for you to have raised that flag yourself. "Not an answer" and "very low quality" post flags are processed fairly quickly, given their sheer quantity. It is certainly possible for mistakes to be made. A flag is a reasonable way to get another moderator to take a second look, if you feel strongly that a mistake was made.

Comment: Answers like this - ones that say "Hi! I have this problem too! Here is my error message: *`[same error as question]`*. *[couple of newlines]* Here is how I solved it: *[completely valid and useful answer]*" - are reasonably common. Flaggers and mods both ought to slow down enough to verify there's no answer included in the post rather than reading the first sentence and reflexively hitting the button to delete the post. Not trying to lob fruit at anyone who made a mistake in this case - just pointing out that it is exemplary of a common class of posts and so this story has a useful moral.

Comment: @Mark I don't think so. _If_ an answerer wants to post their solution to a problem they also encountered, it should be readable as such, namely a solution. Otherwise not only reviewers, but also by later visitors, will dismiss it as a "me too" answer when it's not properly phrased.

Comment: @CodeCaster that may well be an argument for editing the answer - or even for downvoting it, although I wouldn't do so - but surely isn't  a reason for deleting it.

Comment: @Mark that's kind of a catch-22. In order to edit an answer that looks like a non-answer into an answer, you have to recognize it as an answer and not a non-answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster that's where "slow down" comes in. I'm not denying that answers can genuinely give a misleading first-glance impression that they are non-answers, nor that this *can* have a genuinely harmful effect on the answer's usefulness. I *am* saying, though, that answers in that form are common enough that people wielding moderation powers to nuke posts should take the extra few seconds to recognise such answers and deal with them appropriately - and that an appropriate response is not to delete them.

Comment: @MarkAmery [The original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46784458/1) has all the hallmarks of an NAA. I would have voted to delete it at first glance, and I'm someone who understands the [common pitfalls of LQP reviewing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue). In this case, the answerer literally fell through the cracks. That's what Meta and flags are for. Slow down, yes. But this one is too easily missed to say that speed was the issue here.

Comment: @Mark yeah but _that_'s easy to say if we single out a post for which a Meta post was made, where it is explained that if you read carefully it actually _is_ an answer. You're essentially asking moderators to "slow down" on _every_ post flagged as "not an answer", of which I don't know if it's viable. I'm not saying mods should approve or discard flags on a whim, but answerers have a role in the process as well - and I do know writing _is_ hard.

Comment: @Mark There's a natural bias that you are failing to take into account here. This week alone, moderators have processed nearly 20k flags, so if you see one or two Meta posts about mistakes that were made, well, that's still pretty darn good odds. Certainly not enough of a problem for us to make major changes in how long it takes us to process flags. I'm sure you've seen me complain before about people triggering on keywords, but I'm not convinced that's what happened here. The whole answer did not look like useful content. There's no evidence anyone clearly dropped the ball.

Comment: I want to say that I wouldn't have deleted this answer as even its original revision is abundantly clearly an answer to me, but then there are areas where I fail to see how an answer is an answer while other moderators clearly see an answer.

Answer (score -3):

**No, we should not delete such answers.**

Deleting is a destructive action which removes information intended for those trying to solve real world problems. This action must be used with the attention and responsibility expected of it.

For poor answers or those that are difficult to read then down voting or editing rights can be used in a more careless manner with much more positive consequences to the SO community.

Imagine if you did that in a real work place? For example, in code review you wouldn't delete a colleagues work because you thought the first couple lines made the rest of the code seem useless.

Comment: *"For example, in code review you wouldn't delete a colleagues work because you thought the first couple lines made the rest of the code seem useless."* Yeah, you would. Removing dead/useless code happens all the time in code review. I don't know if this answer is supposed to be arguing against the deletion of content altogether, or if you're just saying that particular answer shouldn't have been deleted. No, it shouldn't have, which is why it's now been undeleted. But of course we should prune answers that don't answer the question or don't add meaningful information, and we do all the time.

Comment: @CodyGray --> no need to be defensive. Not arguing against anyone or this particular case. Just answering the question with a firm "no, it shouldn't be" which you indicate that you agree. Please understand the answer is not targeting those involved in this situation. A clear honest mistake in that case.

Comment: As for the code review example --> I mean deleting 150 files if one single line should have been deleted.You'd be fired for destroying entire days of a colleagues work for "I thought these couple of lines were trash so I deleted the whole branch from existence.". I mere example of bad behavior and incorrect use of power.